# setxkbmap returns 65280 when executed from system call

Tags: c++, c

I am sending

```
std::string cmdStr = "setxkbmap us";
int res = system( cmdStr.c_str() );
```

and the result is

```
res: 65280
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Does it have that error when executed from the commandline? Have you looked at the manpage to find out the exit codes?

Comment: That code could also be -256 converted to unsigned short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That value indicates that the child process exited normally with a value of 255.

This could happen if:

- `/bin/sh` couldn't find `setxkbmap`. (*note*: I might be wrong on this one. On my PC, `/bin/sh` returns 127 in that case.)
- `setxkbmap` couldn't open the X server at `$DISPLAY`, including if DISPLAY is unset

I'm sure that there are many other possibilities. Check stdout for error messages.

When interpreting the return value from `system` on Linux, do this:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>


int res = system(foo);
if(WIFEXITED(res)) {
  std::cout << "Normal exit: " << WEXITSTATUS(res) << "\n";
} else {
  if(WIFSIGNALED(res)) {
    std::cout << "Killed by signal #" << WTERMSIG(status);
    if(WCOREDUMP(res)) {
      std::cout << " Core dumped";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "Unknown failure\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For me it says `Normal exit: 255`. I don't know if this is useful info, but if I kill X, add `setxkbmap us` to the X init script and start it again - it changes layout.

Comment: Well, I suspect that my `setxkbmap` has problems with `$DISPLAY`. Smth like `"Cannot open display "default display"`. Then I would have question - is it possible to set or get existing `$DISPLAY` from/before systemcall? Because my program doesn't inherit  `$DISPLAY.

Comment: If you want to update the local display, try `#include <cstdlib> ... setenv("DISPLAY", ":0", 0);` before invoking `system`. If the display is non-local, use the appropriate value in place of `":0"`. If you want to query $DISPLAY, then call `getenv("DISPLAY")`. Its return is either the value or NULL.